# iOS UICollectionView - how to make first cell appear at the bottom of the collection view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using UICollectionView with a flow layout - it has the first item at top left.

**How can I modify flow layout so the first item is at bottom left and more items are added above?**

Maybe there's a comprehensive list of example layouts provided by Apple that I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you make your own implementation of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout and reverse the x positioning yourself.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Subclassing_and_Extending_the_iOS_6_Collection_View_Flow_Layout#Subclassing_the_UICollectionViewFlowLayout_Class